# Exporting multiple Grid Views on a page to mutiple worksheets of a single excel file in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

I know that there a quite a few techniques to export grid view to excel. Below are a few:-

1. HTML Rendering to HTMLTextWriter and Sending the Response Content Type as Excel.
2. Using XML technique and generating the XML String as Excel Sheets.
3. Using Office Interop dlls to create an object for excel document and work on it accordingly.

Now the requirement is, I have multiple Grid Views on a aspx page and these Grid views are loaded from different data sources. I have Export button, which have to export each grid view to separate work-sheet of a single excel file.

This can be done using second and third techniques mentioned above. Want to know the possibility of using the first technique i.e. using HTMLTextWriter

Answer (score 0):

You can do using `Open XML`

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124

http://openxmldeveloper.org/

Comment: What can I do using Open XML?